# How can i activate the wireframe on preview while in solid mode?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Is there any option to show the wireframe while i preview the geometry on solid mode?

Comment: you may be interested in an [addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23747/2217) I wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can enable *Wire* in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]