# Why can't I change the shading of one of my objects from Wireframe to Solid?

Tags: 3d-view

I have two objects in my scene, a boat and a seat. When I try to change the Viewport shading to *Solid*, the seat changes but the boat stays in *Wireframe*. I tried looking for an answer before posting but didn't find one.

[image]

Comment: does the boat has faces ?

Comment: maybe, maybe not :P how do i check for that? (im extremely new to blender)

Comment: thanks Chebhou. that was the problem. i had no faces. must have deleted them at some point somehow! because i had them to begin with.

Comment: you're welcome, your post was clear since you have showed the shading and display panels

Comment: @cegaton i don't know what to write exactly ? plus i'm writing anther one, i'll be back

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake You probably selected all the faces and hit **Delete->Only_Faces**.  So only the vertices and edges remained on the object.

[image]

To check if faces are missing you can go in edit mode and face select mode.
The faces it would look like this:

[image]

No faces will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have your boat body marked as wire in the object tab of the properties panel.
You might find this useful:
[How can i activate the wireframe on preview while in solid mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23830/how-can-i-activate-the-wireframe-on-preview-while-in-solid-mode)