# Custom shortcut

Tags: shortcut

i want to make shortcut for wire displaying (not wireframe mode, displaying wire on top of solid mode), you can find it in the Properties window> Object tab> Display. when i right click there is no "add shortcut" option

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32714/5113

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17822/599. Note that since this is a per-object setting, setting up a shortcut with `wm.context_toggle` will only toggle wire for that particular object. To get the behavior you want (toggling wire for all objects?), you'll have to [write your own operator](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5388/599)

Comment: See [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23747/2217) about the drawing wireframe.

Answer (score 2):

Donwload the "[Display tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Display_Tools)" add-on and assing a shortcut to the "wire on" option

[image]

This allows you to apply effetc to multiple selected object at the same time.

This is a way in wich you can hack the problem.

Comment: Very useful solution for displaying wires to selected objects, there's also a way to display wires to all objects with amaranth tools, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I've found a bit tricky solution, but it works. It's based on keyframing and allows you to switch between desired modes using right and left numpad arrows.
[image]

Go to frame 0 and press <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering the cursor over the *Wire* box in the *Display* panel of the *Object* header.

[image]

Now go to frame 1 (press <kbd>→</kbd>), check the *Wire* box and press <kbd>I</kbd> again. Now you may easily switch between solid and wire modes using left and right arrows.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to display wires for all objects with the amaranth tools, you can find it in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel > *Display* > *Display wireframe*, and you can assign a shortcut to it.